# How do I get the partition offset in OS X with C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, macos

I want to create my own volume id using the drive serial + partition offset + partition size, but I need to know how to get the partition information on OS X. I have (unsucceedingly) tried the following:

```
int fd;
if ((fd = open("/dev/disk0s1", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK)) >= 0) {
    struct hd_geometry geom;
    if (ioctl(fd, 0x0301, &geom) == 0){ //0x0301 is HDIO_GETGEO
        printf("Index = %u\n", geom.start);
    }
    close(fd);
}
```

But even if that were to succeed, it is a flawed solution since as [this](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/ioctl/hdio.txt#85) noted: hd_geometry.start is an unsigned long and "will not contain a meaningful value for disks over 219 Gb in size." Furthermore, I belive that it requires administrative rights, which is also bad. Is there any other way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay last point first. Requiring admin rights is necessary because you are trying to read a raw disk; you could for example potentially seek to a block where a private crypto key is written and read it as an unprivileged user and then where would we be?

Second, /dev/disk0s1 is just a partition and it's also the block-device version of it. You need to read the character device version of the disk, which would be /dev/rdisk0.

Third, HDIO_GETGEO is a linux kernel ioctl (especially consider the 0x0301 value of it)  you are not going to get far on Darwin with this;  Have a look at `<sys/disk.h>` for the related disk IOCTLs. I think DKIOCGETFEATURES / DKIOCGETPHYSICALBLOCKSIZE etc  should get you going.

If you have trouble with these concepts I HIGHLY recommend doing this development in a virtual machine that you can clobber because you do NOT want to accidentally use an IOCTL which will screw up your disks.

### Addendum (possibly the answer)

#### GUID Partition Table

So you are working on Mac OS X / Darwin; We'll assume GUID Partition Table

LBA == Logical Block Addressing ... ; 1 block = 512 bytes

```
LBA 0 - Master Boot Record  (also contained old partition table) 
LBA 1 - GUID Partition Table (standard for OS X) 
LBA 2 - first 4 entries 
LBA 3 - 33 - next 124 entries making for a total of 128 entries
LBA 34 - Partition 1
```

You can grab the second block and start tracing the information

Have a read at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table

It's quite well defined.  GUID uses little-endian byte order for integer values (see examples at the bottom of the wikipedia page)

### Suggestion for testing

Make a copy so that you are not screwing with the actual disks:

dd if=/dev/rdisk0 of=fakedisk count=33

this will create a copy of the first 33 blocks or a disk.
Use fakedisk to test your program out.

### MBR

In case your disk uses MBR use the same concepts as GPT

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_Boot_Record

has excellent description of the sectors.

### Using dtruss fdisk -d /dev/rdisk0 dump to get hints

dtrussing fdisk dump shows that fdisk uses the approach described above.

dtruss fdisk -d /dev/rdisk0

```
SYSCALL(args)            = return
open("/dev/dtracehelper\0", 0x2, 0x7FFF5CFDD5C0)                 = 3 0
__sysctl(0x7FFF5CFDD084, 0x2, 0x7FFF5CFDD070)            = 0 0
bsdthread_register(0x7FFF8BCA41D4, 0x7FFF8BCA41C4, 0x2000)               = 0 0
[[ .... content edited  ... ]]
open("/dev/rdisk0\0", 0x0, 0x7FFF5CFDDD7A)               = 3 0
fstat64(0x3, 0x7FFF5CFDDA10, 0x0)                = 0 0
fstat64(0x3, 0x7FFF5CFDDAC8, 0x0)                = 0 0
ioctl(0x3, 0x40086419, 0x7FFF5CFDDB60)           = 0 0
ioctl(0x3, 0x40046418, 0x7FFF5CFDDB5C)           = 0 0
close(0x3)               = 0 0
open("/dev/rdisk0\0", 0x0, 0x0)          = 3 0
fstat64(0x3, 0x7FFF5CFDDAD0, 0x0)                = 0 0
open("/dev/rdisk0\0", 0x0, 0x0)          = 4 0
fstat64(0x4, 0x7FFF5CFDDA80, 0x0)                = 0 0
lseek(0x4, 0x0, 0x0)             = 0 0
issetugid(0x102C22000, 0x3, 0x7FFF5CFDDC00)              = 0 0
geteuid(0x102C22000, 0x3, 0x0)           = 0 0
[[ tracing data suppressed ]]
read(0x4, "\0", 0x200)           = 512 0
close(0x4)               = 0 0
getrlimit(0x1008, 0x7FFF5CFDCFA8, 0x7FFF8BD0D470)                = 0 0
fstat64(0x1, 0x7FFF5CFDCEF8, 0x7FFF5CFDCFBC)             = 0 0
ioctl(0x1, 0x4004667A, 0x7FFF5CFDCF94)           = 0 0
write_nocancel(0x1, "1,625142447,0xEE,-,1023,254,63,1023,254,63\n\0", 0x2B)              = 43 0
write_nocancel(0x1, "0,0,0x00,-,0,0,0,0,0,0\n\0", 0x17)          = 23 0
write_nocancel(0x1, "0,0,0x00,-,0,0,0,0,0,0\n\0", 0x17)          = 23 0
write_nocancel(0x1, "0,0,0x00,-,0,0,0,0,0,0\n\0", 0x17)          = 23 0
close(0x3)               = 0 0
```

#### deciphering ioctls

How did I figure out that it was these ioctls that are used.

dtruss dump is:

ioctl(0x3, 0x40086419, 0x7FFF5CFDDB60)           = 0 0
ioctl(0x3, 0x40046418, 0x7FFF5CFDDB5C)           = 0 0

and 0x40086518 corresponds to DKIOCGETBLOCKSIZE
This is gleaned by tracing back disk.h (and noting that _IOR expands to _IOC in ioccom.h) and that the last 8 bits correspond to the second number in the IOCTL constant define.

`#define DKIOCGETBLOCKSIZE                     _IOR('d', 24, uint32_t)`

in 0x40086418 the trailing 18(hex)  == 24(dec)

So now that we note that fdisk performs DKIOCGETBLOCKCOUNT and DKIOCGETBLOCKSIZE  to get the physical extents because technically you should use the RESULT of that to figure out LBA offsets (see deciphering ioctls below)

#### The actual read in fdisk

This is how fdisk is doing it:

open("/dev/rdisk0\0", 0x0, 0x0)          = 4 0
read(0x4, "\0", 0x200)           = 512 0
close(0x4)               = 0 0

You can follow suit make sure you replace the 0x200 with the actual block size.

Also, if you're going to use the dd command above to make a copy use the block size as it comes out here.

Comment: As far as admin rights goes, yes, you are correct, but what I meant is that there might be another source (e.g. some IORegistry key that has this data cached and doesnt need admin privlidges to access).

Comment: After hours of searching I cant find a useful non-kernel control code. `DKIOCGETPHYSICALBLOCKSIZE` gets me the block size, but I need the offset. `DKIOCGETFEATURES` does not provide this and I am having a hard time finding something that does. `dk_physical_extent_t` looks like the structure that I want, but it seems to only be accessible via the kernel.

Comment: @chacham15 partition offset I take it you want to know where in the world is the partition bloc starting from?

Comment: Yeah, what from what block on the disk the partition starts.

Comment: I'll add some more info now

Comment: I got this working...after a painfully long amount of time coding and looking through docs/standards for MBR/GPT...Yay!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `DKIOCGETPHYSICALEXTENT` ioctl?  It fills in a `dk_physical_extent_t` structure that includes a 64-bit offset and a 64-bit length.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that and either I am using it wrong or (and i think this is more likely) that is a kernel function which is why I gave up on that approach.

Comment: It's defined in XNU's `bsd/sys/disk.h`, but it's inside `#ifdef KERNEL`, and thus gets stripped out of `/usr/include/sys/disk.h`, so, yes, it's probably only available to kernel-mode code.