# Read boot sector CD drive on macOS

Tags: c#, macos

I am trying to read the boot sector of a cd drive so that I can extract its contents.  Unfortunately, no matter what I do I can't seem to get it working.  I have tried reading the directory as a file but get access denied.  Tried reading right from /dev/disk# and got locked.

I have also tried checking and changing permissions, but nothing.

In Windows, I would use CreateFile & ReadFile from kernel32.  I just am not sure what the macOS equivalent would be.

```
public static List<DriveInfo> GetDrives() => DriveInfo.GetDrives().Where(d => d.IsReady && d.DriveType == DriveType.CDRom).ToList();
public static ReadDrives()
{
  var drives = GetDrives()
  foreach(var drive in drives)
  {
    var root = drive.RootDirectory.FullName;
    using (var fp = File.OpenRead(@"/Volumes/Flash - Copy/"))
    {
       //extract boot here
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Firstly, you need to make sure your program is running as `root`. Unfortunately I don't believe it's as simple as simply using `File.Open...`, `File.Read...`. You will probably have to pinvoke the proper system calls. If you are using Mono, i believe a lot of these are already implemented. If not, you may have some work in front of you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16656218/how-do-i-get-the-partition-offset-in-os-x-with-c-c Here is some source code in C that works with the MBR: https://sourceforge.net/projects/gptfdisk/

Comment: I am using visual studios,  I assume this is mono?  @Andy

Comment: I think it depends on how you created your project. The namespace is `Mono.Unix.Native.Syscall`

Comment: @Andy ok. there is a .netstandard lib for this namespace.  This is a good starting point, thank you very much.

Comment: That's probably not a mono project then. Mono is a cross-platform implementation of the .NET Framework. I still use MonoDevelop and not Visual Studio for Mono apps. So i don't know what you'd do in that case.

Comment: Yeah it is a hacked up Xamarin project that is using .NetStandard

Answer (score 1):

This is not the best answer, but this works for me, no sudo needed.

It is at least a solution for now.

```
var command = $"-c \"umount {inputDisc} && dd if={inputDisc}  of={outputfile} bs=32k  count=1 && mount {inputDisc}\"";
Process.Start("/bin/bash", command);
```